# Trying to get the most inactive members from my guild

Tags: javascript, discord.js, undefined, member

I'm using javascript and discord.js v12 n trying to make `!inactive` cmd, which get's the most inactive members from my server and then mute them. When I try to `console.log(member)` it says 'undefined' please help.

Code:

```
    module.exports = {
    name: "inactive",
    description: "no",
    async execute(message, args, command, client, Discord) {
        if (!message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Isäntä")) return message.channel.send("No perms")

        let userit = new Map()
        let time = ['21600000', '10800000', '7200000', '3600000', '14400000', '18000000']; //1-6h
        let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Muted') //mute role

        message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
            if(member.roles.highest != message.guild.roles.cache.get("706922406257754132")) return;
            userit.set(member.id, member)
        });
       if(userit.size == 0) return message.channel.send("None of users met requirements")
        const inactiveOnes = new Map()
        userit.forEach(member => { 
            if (!member.lastMessage) return inactiveOnes.set(member.id, member)
            if (member.lastMessage.createdTimestamp <= Date.now() - 1209600000) return;
            inactiveOnes.set(member.id, member)
        });
        if(inactiveOnes.size == 0) return message.channel.send("None of users met requirements")
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)+1 
        let random_time = time[Math.floor(Math.random() * time.length)]
        
        for(let i = 0; i < random; i++ ){
          const keys = inactiveOnes.keys();
          let random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * keys)
          const member = keys[random2];
          console.log(member)
          console.log(keys)
         // member.roles.add(muterole.id) 
          message.channel.send(`${member} you have been muted for being inactive! (Time: ${random_time}ms)`)
          setTimeout(() => {
         //   member.roles.remove(muterole.id)
            message.channel.send(`${member} you have been unmuted!`) 
          }, random_time)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `.length` in the bottom for loop.

> ```js
> const keys = inactiveOnes.keys(); 
> let random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length);
> const member = keys[random2];
> console.log(member) console.log(keys)
> ```

Without `.length`, `random2` is set to `NaN`, causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As theusaf mentioned, you missed a `.length` when getting a random number.

```js
const random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length);
```

However, even if you get a number, `member` will still be `undefined`. This is because `inactiveOnes.keys()` doesn't return an array, it returns a `MapIterator`. If you'd like to use array functionality, you could do one of two things.

```js
// 1:
const keys = inactiveOnes.keyArray();

// 2:
const keys = [...inactiveOnes.keys()];
```

Comment: Thanks Lioness100, however, I don't need any more help for this, it has been already fixed.